# not able to checkout files

Tags: svn

The client has asked me to checkout the file and the path is given as follows:

svn+ssh://company/home/svn/payroll

What is the command that would extract the file? The following was tried and did not work.

```
svn co http://company/home/svn/payroll/
```

Nor did this...

```
svn co localhost://company/home/svn/payroll/
```

For the first command I got the error...

```
svn: Repository moved temporarily to 'http://company.in'; please relocate
```

So I tried the following command.

```
svn co http://company.in
```

I got the following message...

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://company.in': 200 OK (http://company.in)
```

I still do not see any files checkedout from repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`svn checkout svn+ssh://company/home/svn/payroll`

Answer (score 0):

try using the "https" protocol, which is commonly used with svn, as follows:

```
svn co https://company/home/svn/payroll/trunk payroll
```

If you want to see what's there with checking stuff out, `svn list`